# Atmospheric pressure question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, atmospheric-science, density

I'm asked to find at what altitude atmospheric pressure falls to 10% of the mean sea level value.

I have found the expression for the variation of pressure with altitude to be
$$p = p_0e^{-h \over a}$$
where the scale factor, $a$, is
$$a = {p_0 \over \rho_0 g}$$

What I've done so far is using values of $p_0 = 1.01$x$10^5$, $\rho_0 =1.21$ and $g = 9.81$, let $p(h) = {1\over 10}p(y)$, but got a value of $-y = 19613$ m

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the answers to [Pressure and altitude](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235936/pressure-and-altitude) as they explain how the pressure:altitude equation is derived.

There is nothing wrong with our working, but you have assumed that the temperature is constant and in reality the temperature falls with altitude ([in the troposphere at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troposphere)). That means the pressure falls more rapidly with height than your equation suggests. The haeight at which $P/P_0 = 0.1$ is more like 16km.